# Why doesn't the button appear in my audio player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I am trying to make an audio playlist mainly using Javascript but a play button image isn't appearing and I just can't figure out why. Can anyone spot it?

I have added an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L0n1.jpg) of what the website looks like. Everything else seems to be working, including the play function when you click where the button is supposed to be, but the image does not appear.

HTML:

```
<div id="trackbox"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.playbutton
{ 
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    width:19px; 
    height:22px;
    margin:14px 0px 0px 14px; 
    background:url(../Assets/Images/play_button.png) no-repeat; 
    color: #F9690E;
    border:none; 
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    window.onload = function() 
{
init();
}
function init()
{
    console.log('init fired');
}
function _(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function FeedTheMachineAlbum(){
    var audio = new Audio();
    var audio_folder = "Assets/Music/FeedTheMachine/";
    var audio_ext = ".m4a";
    var audio_index = 1;
    var is_playing = false;
    var playingtrack;
    var trackbox = _("trackbox");
    var tracks = {
        "track1":["Feed the Machine", "01FeedTheMachine"],
        "track2":["Coin for the Ferryman", "02CoinForTheFerryman"],
        "track3":["Song on Fire", "03SongOnFire"],
        "track4":["Must be Nice", "04MustBeNice"],
        "track5":["After the Rain", "05AfterTheRain"],
        "track6":["For the River", "06ForTheRiver"],
        "track7":["Home", "07Home"],
        "track8":["The Betrayal (Act III)", "08TheBetrayal(ActIII)"],
        "track9":["Silent Majority", "09SilentMajority"],
        "track10":["Every Time We're Together", "10EveryTimeWe'reTogether"],
        "track11":["The Betrayal(Act I)", "11TheBetrayal(ActI)"]
    };
    for(var track in tracks){
        var trackbar = document.createElement("div");
        var playbutton = document.createElement("button");
        var trackname = document.createElement("div");
        trackbar.className = "trackbar";
        playbutton.className = "playbutton";
        trackname.className = "trackname";
        trackname.innerHTML = audio_index+". "+tracks[track][0];
        playbutton.id = tracks[track][1];
        playbutton.addEventListener("click", switchTrack);
        trackbar.appendChild(playbutton);
        trackbar.appendChild(trackname);
        trackbox.appendChild(trackbar);
        audio_index++;
    }
    audio.addEventListener("ended",function(){
        _(playingtrack).style.background = "url(../Assets/Images/play_button.png)";
        playingtrack = "";
        is_playing = false;
    });
    function switchTrack(event){
        if(is_playing){
            if(playingtrack != event.target.id){
                is_playing = true;
                _(playingtrack).style.background = "url(../Assets/Images/play_button.png)";
                event.target.style.background = "url(../Assets/Images/pause_button.png)";
                audio.src = audio_folder+event.target.id+audio_ext;
                audio.play();
            } else {
                audio.pause();
                is_playing = false;
                event.target.style.background = "url(../Assets/Images/play_button.png)";
            }
        } else {
            is_playing = true;
            event.target.style.background = "url(../Assets/Images/pause_button.png)";
            if(playingtrack != event.target.id){
                audio.src = audio_folder+event.target.id+audio_ext;
            }
            audio.play();
        }
        playingtrack = event.target.id;
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", FeedTheMachineAlbum);
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with layering (z-index) or other CSS. Will be tough to diagnose without a demo. Can you at least post some rendered markup so we can see what the DOM structure ends up looking like?

Comment: @Gabby2805 perhaps you should create a jsfiddle for this as there is no real context to the question

Comment: Will you open dev tools and see if there are any 404 requests for `play_button.png`?

Comment: I've played around with the z-index and doesn't seem to work. This is my first time asking for help on here so sorry if its not the best. There are no console errors.

Comment: I can see a button when I enter your code in JSFiddle and enter the URL of an image that is allowed to be linked. Try an online source that allows hotlinking and see if that helps you. Possibly your URL is invalid or you lack permission to link your image.

Comment: Thank you KVNSTOBJEKT, I tried different images and it works. I have no idea why I wasn't able to use the ones I originally had but nevermind - problem solved!